# connecting 2 wifi routers wirelessly

Tags: networking, wireless-networking

I have 2 routers and a dsl modem. DSL Modem is connected to wifi-router1 and I can access internet from wifi-router1. How to connect another router wifi-router2 to wifi-router1 wirelessly? I want to extend the range of my wifi signals but dont want to connect these 2 routers via cable?

wifi-router2 supports Lazy, Bridge and Repeater mode.

Answer (score 0):

I have found some couple of links might help you please check them out:

[Networking & wireless forum: how to connect two routers wirelessly](http://forums.cnet.com/7723-7589_102-340637.html)

[How to Connect Two Wireless Routers Together](http://www.labnol.org/internet/connect-two-routers/13517/)

Answer (score 0):

Typically, you would use wireless repeater mode to rebroadcast a signal too weak for your wireless clients to pick up. To increase the range further you can attach antenna if your wireless router supports.

Read your router's documentation. You will find it helpful.